# SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML Response

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

while using wso2is-5.6.0
 "travelocity.com" application is configure with wso2 identity server to authentication from Facebook am getting this error

org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML Response

after google search there some mention that upload certificate file but am not getting this point which certificate file and from where i will get certificate file to upload in identity provider in wso2 identity server

Answer (score 1):

This happens because, your travelocity sample doesn't have the certificate which is corresponding to the key used by Identity server to sign the SAML response. One of the easiest options is to replace the key stores of your travelocity sample with the ones inside WSO2 identity server (Assuming you are using out of the box setup). You can find the key stores in your identity server distribution /repository/resources/security directory. Copy two key stores (wso2carbon.jks and client truststore.jks) to your /WEB-INF/classes. (yes you need to replace existing ones).

Or else if you have changed keys in your wso2 IS, the proper way to do fix this is, export the public key from Identity Server (from wso2carbon.jks) and import it to both (wso2carbon.jks and clinttrustore.jks) in travelocity sample. You can use keytool commands to achieve this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the exact commands we should use to achieve the second part  ? (the proper way to fix this)